# Using Code Climate for Test Coverage alongside Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, code-coverage

My company is currently trying to implement Code Climate for test coverage. However, I do not have much idea about it and new to using code climate.

I tried to integrate code climate with Jenkins so that once the tests are successful, I can simply move on with other Jenkins Job.

I consulted the documentation itself, and as per documentation there are things like but there is not much explanation about it.

`./cc-test-reporter after-build -t simplecov --exit-code $? || echo  “Skipping Code Climate coverage upload”`

I executed this, but returned there is no such file simplecov. I later found that the -t flag is used to provide the file which will be used for coverage. Below is my Jenkins job.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "---------------------------------------"
echo "| Downloading Code Climate "
curl -L https://codeclimate.com/downloads/test-reporter/test-reporter-latest-linux-amd64 >> ./cc-test-reporter
chmod +x ./cc-test-reporter
echo "| Download Complete "
echo "---------------------------------------"


CODECLIMATE_REPO_TOKEN=${CODECLIMATE_REPO_TOKEN}
echo "Running tests"
./cc-test-reporter before-build.
```

Once I execute this, I get the following output.

```
---------------------------------------
| Downloading Code Climate 
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   178  100   178    0     0    933      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   936

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100 12.1M  100 12.1M    0     0  10.0M      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 15.8M
| Download Complete 
---------------------------------------
Running tests
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Why am I not getting any code coverage or things like that in the console. How do I properly integrate it in Jenkins.

**`UPDATE`**
I have successfully created the job without issue.
Now the problem I am facing is

```
$ ./cc-test-reporter format-coverage -t lcov coverage/lcov.info -d -o codeclimate.json
DEBU[0000] coverage path coverage/lcov.info             
DEBU[0000] using formatter lcov                         
DEBU[0000] checking search path coverage/lcov.info for lcov formatter 
DEBU[0000] couldn't load branch from ENV, trying git... 
DEBU[0000] couldn't load commit sha from ENV, trying git... 
DEBU[0000] couldn't load committed at from ENV, trying git... 
Error: could not find coverage info for source files

user@host:app$ pwd
app
user@host:app$ ll
coverage
user@host:app$ ll coverage
lcov-report
lcvo.info
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been resolved.
This is for nodejs

Need to install necessary dependencies either using yarn or npm.
Once done, run

```
nyc --reporter=lcov yarn unit unit
$ ./cc-test-reporter after-build -t lcov --exit-code $?
```